# Amazon Lex Default Version Problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

In my AWS Lex project, I have multiple intents with similar sample utterances.

For example, "Create new inspection" and "Create new task" are two sample utterances. In my intent list, "creating a new inspection" is listed before the "new task" intent. **When misspelling my utterances into the chatbox, for example, "create new taskfdsaf", AWS Lex thinks that the intent is "create new inspection" and respectively calls the AWS Lambda function for a "new inspection".** I assume it's because it has low confidence and is going by the order of intents on the list.

Is there any way to fix this in the non-advanced version of AWS Lex? On the version I am currently using, no confidence scores are being created.

Answer (score 0):

Consider redesigning your bot and combing your two mentioned intents into one.

Create a slot for `activity` (as an example), where the possible values for `activity` could be:-

- Inspection
- Task

Your lambda function would then be responsible for acting accordingly based on the slot value.